# Cucumber features are hanging on console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

In my rails application, I have 2000 lines of code for cucumber features.

Now I am running all of the features at once using command rake rcov:features for getting coverage report.

I observed that while running all at once, they hang at some of the features and, because of this, are not generating the coverage report.

Please suggest, what are the possibilities of getting hanged?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when the code depended on modernizer, and it was removed. I have also seen this happen when an incompatible/unbuildable server is specified in the gemfile (in this case, a broken build of thin on Windows). I have also seen machines with issues using selenium, and none using capybara-webkit, and vice-versa. Basically, there are about a million things that can go wrong, it seems to me that rails testing in general will benefit from additional polish and improved interaction. I wonder if you would have an easier time starting off small, instead of trying to find out exactly where in the 2000 lines it is all at once, perhaps it would be easier to remove all but a little bit of the code, and add it in slowly, until something fails. You could do the same thing, using your git repo, if this has worked in the past. Break it up into a smaller, simper, and more digestible project.